# Strange use of sigma notation in computability

Tags: summation, computability

Ok everyone, so I was reading about computability when I came across the following-

''Suppose that $f(x, z)$ is any function; the *bounded sum* $\sum_{z<y} f(x, z)$ is a function of $x, y$ given by the following recursion equation:

$\sum_{z<0} f(x, z) = 0$

$\sum_{z<y+1} f(x, z) = \sum_{z<y} f(x, z)$ + $f(x, y)$"

I have never seen sigma notation using the less-than symbol like this before, and I've been thinking about it for hours and have no idea of how to interpret it. It would be super helpful if someone could give an example as well, say if the function $f(x, z)$ in the above passage were the addition function or something (*i.e.* $f(x, z) = x + z$).

Comment: It means to sum over all z that satisfy the condition. For example in the last sum you give it means to sum up all z that are less than y

Comment: Ok, so say $f(x, z) = x + z$, and say that $x = 2$. Then, in this case, would 
$\sum_{z<1} f(2, z) = 2$ ? And would $\sum_{z<2} f(2, z) = 5$ ? etc...

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: _Excellent_, thank you.